# PHP Sending Email Error

Tags: php, email

I'm trying to send an email using PHP code, I'm sure the code is right but I'm not receiving any emails. Can anyone see a problem with this code:

```
<?php
    $to = 'i7906890@bournemouth.ac.uk';
    $subject = 'Registration Complete';
    $message = 'Thank you for joining us at Arsenic & Vice';
    $header = 'From: admin@arsenicandvice.co.uk';
    if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $header)){
        echo('<p>Sent</p>');
        } else {
        echo('<p>Fail</p>');
    }
?>
```

Comment: Is `admin@arsenicandvice.co.uk' a valid E-Mail address? Is it linked to the outgoing server? The domain doesn't seem to be reachable?

Comment: Looks fine, maybe a spam filter is catching it. Does your mailserver log show the message being sent?

Comment: check your mail server's logs to see what happens after php hands over the email. remember: PHP doesn't actually deliver it. It just drops the letter in the mailbox - could be the postal service that's trashing the mail.

Comment: admin@arsenicandvice.co.uk isn't a valid email, will this produce an issue?

We get the fail message upon sending

Comment: That will be one issue and may lead to the message being filtered out, yeah. (If you get a fail message though, please edit it into your question)

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code on my server and it works fine, I've received the e-mail.

I've also run it so you can receive it on i7906890@...

The problem is on your hosting. Either your e-mail server (qmail...) has a long queue or it is stuck. Contact your server admin.